# types of variables: global, application, session or cookies variables in swift?

Tags: swift, global-variables, session-variables, session-cookies

I have an "x" viewController which when I press a button, the view is reload and the data is updated in the same view with new values but when the view is reload, miss i the old values (this can happen several times) and also i must save this data in any array and then send them all together in the last step. When i press the button i use to reload the view:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mvx_id") as! xController, animated: true)
```

I don't know how I can save this data and don't get lost when I update the view, what I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create the view controller first and assign the array to a property you create on it, then transition to it.

Comment: But how do i assign the array to the view that is load? because I used to pass values from one view to another but i did with segue but does not apply because I can not do segue to the same view.

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question correctly. If you need to update an array with a button press in the same class you can just append an object to the array, or re declare the entire array.

Comment: I don't explain it well, when I press a button, the view is reload and the data is updated in the same view with new values but when the view is reload, miss i the old values

Comment: Got ya, I think a less intense solution would to be to just reload the views that need reloading and not the whole entire instance of the view controller. If you need to you can store things in core data or NSUserDefaults.

Comment: thanks for your help, i searched about NSUserDefaults and it works for me
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() userDefaults.setInteger(value, forKey: "keyValue")
and then i can use this value in any view